# Resize image From url objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I return an image from an url with

```
 NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Result]];
```

and i store it to google map marker i want to resize it to half size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
UIImage *actualImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(actualImage.size.width/2, actualImage.size.height/2);
[actualImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,actualImage.size.width/2, actualImage.size.height/2)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData *smallData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);
```

Comment: yes but this returns UIImage i want NSSData to put it to GMSMarker

Answer (score 1):

To resize the image after it has been downloaded from an URL, you can use mainly 2 methods:

- Use Core Graphics (as suggested), but pay attention about the aspect ratio
- Use ImageIO

In the first case you should create a space in memory to redraw the downloaded image at a small size, that's a brief description of the snippet posted.
Those are 2 frameworks available both for OSX and iOS, my suggestion is to use [NYXImagesKit](https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit) if using third party library is not a problem. It has very helpful method to handle images also one to download images from a URL in a correct way.
What you are doing can be bad for the user experience, the way you are download data from a URL creates a synchronous connection that will block the main thread until the method has finished. The main thread manages most of  the UI interactions. This is not good, because imagine that the server is not responding and the timeout is set to 60 seconds, the user will have to wait 60 seconds before make an further action on the app. the same happen if th image is too big and the connection poor.
To correctly download data you should use an asynchronous method, the library above has what you are looking for.

Comment: Could you give me example of first method as you have mentioned Core Graphics (with aspect ratio)

Comment: Just take a look at NYXimageskit source code or here http://code.developwithus.com/iphone/resize-image-in-iphone-sdk/